# Visual Studio stack alignment for x86

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to force Visual Studio (2013) compiler to align stack to 16 bytes?

AFAIK, the default stack alignment for x86 is 4 bytes. Default stack alignment for amd64 is 16 bytes. So, I'm just interesting in "fixing" the stack alignment in x86 only.